# Using "if" condition inside junit element in apache ant script

Tags: if-statement, ant, junit

I have tried to use "if-then-else" condition inside junit element in a build.xml file and I am getting the following error while trying to build.

**junit doesn't support the nested "if" element**

Is there a work around for this issue?

Comment: are you using it inside a fileset ?

Comment: Not exactly.. you won't be able to use the if inside junit, but there may be a different way to accomplish your ultimate goal.  What are you trying to make conditional about your junit task?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your code, explain exactly what you want to do (i.e. why you need to include an if/then/else in your junit) and what your output looks like? Otherwise, your question will be closed.

Comment: @LakshithaRanasingha No, i tried to use it inside junit.

Comment: @DavidW. I was trying to set the jvmarg values for code coverage using emma inside junit. But I wanted to collect the unit tests' coverage data only when emma is enabled. I tried to check if emma is enabled or not, using an if condition inside junit. Because this didn't work, I wrote the if condition outside junit and modified the ant script inside junit - if emma is enabled I set the jvmarg values otherwise I don't. This solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since Ant 1.9.1 which has been released this week, you can put `if` and `unless` attributes on arbitrary Ant tasks.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html