# How can I provide a conditional jvmarg for the ant junit command?

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, ant, continuous-integration

Our shop has multiple build and test environments (Jenkins, Ant 1.9.6) set up on Java 6, 7 and 8. On Java 7 only, in order for our tests to run successfully, we need to add the JVM argument `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`.

I can't use a `condition` inside `junit`, so I set a boolean property in the `init` task:

```
<condition property="usesplitverifier">
    <equals arg1="${ant.java.version}" arg2="1.7" />
</condition>
```

In my `test` task, I need to add `jvmarg` to `junit` only if that property is `true`:

```
<echo message="usesplitverifier: ${usesplitverifier}" />

<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" fork="yes" forkmode="once" tempdir="${build.dir}">
    <jvmarg if="usesplitverifier" value="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" />
    ...
</junit>
```

The output is:

```
        [echo] usesplitverifier: true

BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\util\build.xml:141: jvmarg doesn't support the "if" attribute
```

I'm trying to avoid adding [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) to our build/test environment. Also, I'd like to avoid adding more targets to the build script (I'm trying to simplify the build process). Is there another approach that might work here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I was writing this question, I found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16741557/2074605) in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16739652/2074605) that was closed as being too vague. I decided to post this question in order to provide a specific use case.

The [if/unless namespaces](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) may be used in any Ant command. In my case, I needed to add the `if` namespace to the project:

```
<project name="my-project" xmlns:if="ant:if" ...>
```

And then put the conditional on `jvmarg` as follows:

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" fork="yes" forkmode="once" tempdir="${build.dir}">
    <jvmarg if:set="usesplitverifier" value="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" />
    ...
</junit>
```

The reason `if:set` works in this case is that if `${ant.java.version}` is not `1.7`, the property remains unset.

Caveats (acceptable in my case):

- The `if/unless` namespaces are only available since Ant 1.9.1.
- Prior to Ant 1.6, `${ant.java.version}` returns the version of the JVM that Ant was compiled with.